# Error:Cannot locate service of type FileOperations, as ProjectScopeServices has been closed

Tags: android, gradle

I changed `build.gradle` of my project from:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0-beta2'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.4.0-alpha3'
```

now I got this error:

```
Gradle 'AndroidStudioProjects' project refresh failed
Error:Cannot locate service of type FileOperations, as ProjectScopeServices has been closed.
```

all of my `build.gradle`:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.4.0-alpha3'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to call `gradlew stop` to stop the gradle deamon, at least worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and after reading a little into this, it's a known issue in the build and they're working on it.  I managed to solve it though, at least for myself.
I went to https://gradle.org/releases and downloaded 3.4.1 manually then unzipped to my drive.

Next I went to settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle

I set it for Use Local Gradle Distribution, pointing to where I put gradle.  Make sure the directory you choose is the root of the current version, so that bin is directly under that directory.

After that, I was able to sucessfully run a clean build and then sync gradle again.

(Oh and in case anyone is wondering, the issue is [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=246383)
Hopefully this helps!